# Sencha Cmd build error while building an ExtJs App extending 3rd party classes (non-extJs classes)

Tags: extjs, cmd, external

I have an extJs 4 app that is extending 3rd party non-extJs classes. I just can't seem to build the app. It keeps giving me the error below. Objective is to minify the app with appropriate dependencies since it is taking longer time to load both libraries and slowing down the application.

I am using Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84.

/*************************************************/

C2008: Requirement had no matching files

[ERR]

[ERR] BUILD FAILED

[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files

/*************************************************/

Any help is truly appreciated.

So far I have tried:

1) modified app/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg classpath to include the external library. No luck.
2) Added  to  section of the index.html. No luck.
3) Added loaders and set path of the external library. No luck.

External library is already on my local machine inside of the app folder.

Anyone out there?

I take you out for a lunch if you help me resolve this issue. No seriously!

This is really a showstopper for me.

Thank you,

Ritesh

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved in the Sencha Forum post below.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285252-Sencha-Cmd-build-ExtJs-with-external-library&p=1043385#post1043385

If you can't get to the link then....

If a testing build works and production build does not you might try disabling optimizations. If you look in ".sencha/app/production.defaults.properties" you will see the various settings that make production builds unique.

Try adding this setting:

build.optimize=${build.optimize.disable}

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks,

Ritesh

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **extend** a 3rd party class as `Ext.define` expects that all classes inherit from `Ext.Base` what is unlikely for non-ext 3rd party lib.

Of course, you can **use** a third party lib by including its javascript outside of <x-compile> block in your `index.html`

Comment: Saki,

Thanks for your response.

So what happens if you extend a non-ext class? My entire product is built on that concept and working like a charm. Only gotcha is that during the build process it's complaining. 

I also read in Sencha Cmd docs that if external library is not written in Ext format then you. Can use //@define or //@require to keep the compiler happy. 

From Sencha perspective: it doesn't make sense that just to build / minify the app I have to abandon the idea of extending the non-ext classes. 

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Ritesh